# How to make Guest (Windows 10) full screen in iOS (host) in Virtual-Box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, multiple-monitors

I am using `Windows10` as `Virtual-box` guest from `iOS` host. It works fine, except the fact that I cant make the Guest as full screen i.e. occupying entire screen of my iMac without distorting the aspect ratio and resolution.

When I searched over internet, I found that many people suggested to install the `VirtualBox_Extension_Pack`, which I downloaded from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.0/. But I failed to install that as when I click on `Guest -> Insert Guest Addition CD Image`, I dont see any popup opens the installation of ISO image of `VirtualBox_Extension_Pack`. Next I checked the settings and I see that is already available (as referred in attached snapshot)

[image]

I also tried using `View -> Virtual Screen1 -> Scale to 150%`. But with that, the screen is just getting larger and thereby failed to display entire window in my monitor.

Is there any concrete guide how to achieve that? I am using `Virtual Box` version `6.1`

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try as the fix is not "host specific".

*Note this will work in cases where underlying display settings have **not** been changed (on your guest OS) **or you can revert them back**. By doing so this fix is more likely to work. 
*This fix does not involve amending Guest Additions in the Devices tab.

1. Head over to your Guest OS screen and check display settings of Guest OS (I kept Video memory at 16MB (default) but you could try increasing this to 64MB or 128MB afterwards if no joy and I left Enable 3D option **unchecked**).
2. Obtain your actual host monitor setting i.e. device manager/system information or download ***Speccy*** (a software by the makers of CC Cleaner)
3. In the Guest OS '''Settings''' - amend '''Display''' settings to match the host/actual resoloution of your monitor by selecting the appropriate option on the dropdown menu.
4. This may complete your fix, otherwise check '''scaling''' settings on Guest OS, setting path; **View** > **Virtual screen** = ensure this is scaled **100%** only.

Here is a video I quickly made if needed; https://youtu.be/mI5kHxNafM8

Comment: My Mac resolution is - 21.5-inch (1920 x 1080). This option is not available in Windows 10